# Put two (side by side) buttons as a right side overlay of an UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, overlay

(Swift3/iOS10)

I'm trying to put two buttons (save/cancel) inside of a `UITextField` using the `rightView` property. My basic setup code (called from `viewDidLoad`) is as follows:

```
private func accesorizeRenameField() {
    let saveButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    saveButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "buttonCheckmark"), for: .normal)
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(renameSave), for: .touchUpInside)
    saveButton.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.15, alpha: 1)

    let cancelButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    cancelButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "buttonX"), for: .normal)
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(renameCancel), for: .touchUpInside)
    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor(227, 34, 60, 1)

    let container = UIView()
    container.addSubview(saveButton)
    container.addSubview(cancelButton)
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    saveButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    cancelButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    cancelButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    saveButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    saveButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    cancelButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    cancelButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    self.renameField.rightView = container
    self.renameField.rightViewMode = .always
}
```

Later on, when I expose the rename field through some animation, I call

```
self.renameField.rightView?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.renameField.bounds.height * 2, height: self.renameField.bounds.height)
self.renameField.rightView?.setNeedsLayout()
"rightView.frame \(self.renameField.rightView?.frame)".print()
self.renameField.rightView?.subviews.enumerated().forEach() {index,child in
    "child \(index) frame \(child.frame)".print()
}
```

However, I cannot get the buttons to show up. The cyan background (for debugging) shows up, but actually is square (it should be a 2:1 rectangle). The `print` shows that the subviews have frames of size 0. What is the *right*/*idiomatic* way to do this? I feel like I'm just throwing hammers here...

Comment: The UIView and buttons should have their translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to false. I'd experiment and see if you can just get a plain UIView with a colored background to show (I seem to recall the textField wants this view to be square and something like 44x44 in size, but not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create UIButton as type of .custom instead of .system.

And as you already know renameField's height in viewDidLoad, you don't need to bother with constraint.

The code below is enough.

```
override func
viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let wSize = renameField.frame.size.height - 2

    let saveButton = UIButton( type: .custom )
    saveButton.setImage( #imageLiteral(resourceName: "buttonCheckmark"), for: .normal )
    saveButton.addTarget( self, action: #selector(renameSave), for: .touchUpInside )
    saveButton.frame = CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: wSize, height: wSize )

    let cancelButton = UIButton( type: .custom )
    cancelButton.setImage( #imageLiteral(resourceName: "buttonX"), for: .normal )
    cancelButton.addTarget( self, action: #selector(renameCancel), for: .touchUpInside )
    cancelButton.frame = CGRect( x: wSize, y: 0, width: wSize, height: wSize )

    let wV = UIView()
    wV.frame = CGRect( x:0, y:0, width: wSize * 2, height: wSize )
    wV.addSubview( saveButton )
    wV.addSubview( cancelButton )

    renameField.rightView = wV;
    renameField.rightViewMode = .always;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was trying to hard I guess.